# python mcrypt bug when there is a dollar in salt

Tags: python, mcrypt

Look at this:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
>>> import crypt
>>> print(crypt.crypt("16409","$1awesome"))
None
```

if i remove the dollar char:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
>>> import crypt
>>> print(crypt.crypt("16409","1awesome"))
1auXW8qPKwars
```

Do you think this is a bug ?

Thanks

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/crypt.html#crypt.crypt), **The characters in salt must be in the set [./a-zA-Z0-9].**

Comment: Thank you, do you know another python lib which can works with $ in salt ?

Comment: You can `base64` the salt to only get alphanumeric chars